# python find specific pattern of text from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to extract specific type of text from string.

```
Luxyry 2 bedroom apartment
Deluxe apartment 2 bedroom
Super luxyry 3 bedroom apartment
1 Bedroom studio apartment
```

This is the text I have and I want to extract `1 Bedroom` or `2 bedroom` or `3 bedroom` from the text.
The pattern will be the same like {no_of_bedroom} bedroom.

How to extract this in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of re module

```
#pip install re

Import re
text = 'Luxyry 2 bedroom apartment
        Deluxe apartment 2 bedroom
        Super luxyry 3 bedroom 
           apartment 1 Bedroom studio apartment'
Result = re.findall(r"\d+\s\[Bb]bedroom", text)
Print(f"Result :{Result}")
```

\d+ will match 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` like the below:

```
import re
text = """
Luxyry 2 bedroom apartment
Deluxe apartment 2 bedroom
Super luxyry 3 bedroom apartment
1 Bedroom studio apartment
"""

res = re.findall(r'\d+ [Bb]edroom', text)
print(res)

# Use 'set()' if you want unique values
# print(set(res))
# {'3 bedroom', '1 Bedroom', '2 bedroom'}
```

Output:

```
['2 bedroom', '2 bedroom', '3 bedroom', '1 Bedroom']
```

Explanation:

- `\d+`:

  - `\d` : Matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
  - `+`  : Matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
- `[Bb]` : Match a single character present in the list below `[Bb]`

Comment: Be warned that you are using `re` which is part of standard library, whilst [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) is external library